# Subquery getting latest column value from rows and collapsing result into a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that outputs this result from the main query, sorted by descending date(latest being the top)

```
 colA         colb      colc
 ----------------------------
 null         null      null
 True         null      null
 False        null      null
 null         True      null
 null         null      False
```

I'd like the end result to look like this

```
 colA     colB   colC
 -----------------------
 True     True   False
```

One could use a bool_or aggregate function, but it wouldn't work in a case like this:

```
 colA         colb      colc
 -----------------------------
 null         null      null
 False        null      null
 True         null      null
 null         True      null
 null         null      False
```

The output of this would be

```
 colA      colB   colC
 ----------------------
 False     True   False
```

Basically, I need to traverse every row in each column, and get the earliest value that is not null and return that.

So far I'm using first_value to get window function to get the first value , but unfortunately all rows in the table

```
select first_value(cola) over() as cola 
from my_data 
where cola is not null;
```

returns

```
  cola
  -----
   f
   f
```

If i try to do first_value for the other columns, it will not return anything since the amount of rows do no match in each column

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
with t (date, cola, colb, colc) as ( values
    (current_date, null,  null,  null),
    (current_date - 1, true,  null,  null),
    (current_date - 2, false, null,  null),
    (current_date - 3, null,  true,  null),
    (current_date - 4, null,  null,  false)
)
select
    (array_agg(fv_cola) filter (where fv_cola is not null))[1] as cola,
    (array_agg(fv_colb) filter (where fv_colb is not null))[1] as colb,
    (array_agg(fv_colc) filter (where fv_colc is not null))[1] as colc
from (
    select
        first_value(cola) over(
            partition by cola is null
            order by date desc
        ) as fv_cola,
        first_value(colb) over(
            partition by colb is null
            order by date desc
        ) as fv_colb,
        first_value(colc) over(
            partition by colc is null
            order by date desc
        ) as fv_colc
    from t
) s
;
 cola | colb | colc 
------+------+------
 t    | t    | f
```